# How to use alignment guides in swift ui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-alignment-guide

Simply what I'm trying to achieve is this
[image]

The Circle aligned to the bottom left edge of the other image
I know that alignment guides should be used in this scenario, but I truly can't understand the concept, that's what I've done so far.

```
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                Image("image_placeholder")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: .infinity, height: 220)
                
                Image("image_placeholder")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 200)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .alignmentGuide(.bottom) { d in
                        d[VerticalAlignment.center]
                    }
                    .alignmentGuide(.leading) { d in
                        d[HorizontalAlignment.leading]
                    }
            }
```

But that code displays image in the center bottom, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the ZStack alignment to bottomLeading

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).